# point- to – point local switching

Tags: cisco, cisco-asr, cisco-ios-xr, l2vpn

I want to build an point- to – point local E-line carrier Ethernet services between IOS XRv routers using the link bundles.
Once the two local EFPs linked with a point-to-point cross connect, the state of the cross-connect becomes up. But still the ping between CEs failed.

What could be the problem?

Below are the output details of IOS XRv router confgiuration,

PE1:

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE1#sh run | begin xconnect
Tue Jan 16 18:26:15.215 UTC
Building configuration...

**xconnect group test

p2p test1

interface Bundle-Ether100

interface Bundle-Ether101**

!

RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE1#sh run int bundle-ether 100

Tue Jan 16 18:28:23.989 UTC

interface Bundle-Ether100

l2transport

!

RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE1#sh run int bundle-ether 101

Tue Jan 16 18:28:27.894 UTC

interface Bundle-Ether101

l2transport
```

CE1:

```
interface Bundle-Ether100

ipv4 address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0

!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/3

bundle id 100 mode on

! 
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/4

bundle id 100 mode on
```

CE2:

```
interface Bundle-Ether101

ipv4 address 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.0

!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/5

bundle id 101 mode on

! 
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/6

bundle id 101 mode on
```